# Just-installed Alfresco does not return a latestChangeLogToken: Is it OK in regard to the CMIS protocol?

Tags: alfresco, standards-compliance, cmis

Here is what I did:

1. Installed+started+stopped Alfresco 5.0.c
2. [Enabled CMIS ChangeLog](https://github.com/aegif/CmisSync/wiki/How-to-enable-CMIS%27-ChangeLog-feature-on-Alfresco) in Alfresco
3. Started Alfresco again
4. Sent a request to `http://server/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom/changes`

**PROBLEM**: [The HTTP response](https://gist.github.com/nicolas-raoul/6e549a426fe13b18a198) does **NOT** contain a `<cmis:latestChangeLogToken>` element.

Is that OK in regards to the [CMIS protocol](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/os/CMIS-v1.1-os.html)?

Am I doing something wrong?
Or should I just assume a null value as a token, and be assured that from the next change the ChangeLog token will never become null again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not OK in regard to the CMIS specification.

All requests to `http://server/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom/changes` MUST return a token when ChangeLog is enabled.

From the [CMIS 1.1 specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/os/CMIS-v1.1-os.html#x1-12700015):

> 2.1.15.3 "Latest Change Token" repository information
>   Repositories that support the changeLogToken event MUST expose the latest change log token (i.e. the change log token corresponding to the most recent change to any object in the repository) as a property returned by the getRepositoryInfo service.

Comment: Have you reported this as a bug to Alfresco?